# Photo gallery with infinite scrolling, dynamically loaded images and others

Tags: android, android-gallery

I would like to create photo gallery in my app. My requirements are:

- infinite scrolling (like in Infinite Gallery http://blog.blundell-apps.com/infinite-scrolling-gallery/)
- view - like in the picture below - selected photo is visible and on the right there is small part of next photo

[image]

- pics are dynamically downloaded from server while scrolling - problem is that I don't have ready url list before creating gallery - I only have codename for image, for example:

  - codename is "photocar",
  - and url for the images are like:

  http://www.MY_SERVER.com/pics/photocar1.png

  http://www.MY_SERVER.com/pics/photocar2.png

  http://www.MY_SERVER.com/pics/photocar5.png

  ...

  (after codename there is counter). I don't know how much images there is but assume that I want to add max 20 images (if exists), another problem is that image counter is not continuous - I mean sometimes only images 1, 2, 3 exists, but sometimes it may be 3, 5, 10, 19. How to check which ones exists and add them do gallery (I thought about opening HttpURLConnection and checking response code but it's pretty slow)?
- images have different sizes and aspect ratio so they have to be cut to aspect ratio around 16:9

What's the best approach?

Comment: what have you done till now? 
what have you tried or implemented?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to use Infinite Gallery and connected it with downloading images from url based on ImageLoader from Lazy List (https://github.com/thest1/LazyList), I also wrote a method to cut images to aspect ratio 16:9 which is working pretty good with horizontal images (but with aspect ratio different than 16:9) but it's not working with vertical images. I try to create urls for images with AsyncTask and  HttpURLConnection and check response code, if it is HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK then I add url do gallery adapter list (but it's pretty slow).